# Store procedure to copy a table to two anoter table

Tags: mysql

I want to copy a table in to two different tables 
for this I have written following procedure.
I want to concate temp1 table's fname and lname and want to put in another table atom with a string value 'Person'.
After inserting the value at table atom I want inserted id and with this inserted id(`g_id`) insert data to new table user.

```
 DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE  cpy()
     BEGIN
     insert into atom values(name,type) select  concat(temp1.fname,temp.lname), 'Person' from temp1;
    SET g_id= LAST_INSERT_ID();
    insert into user(id,mobno,password,fname,lname,mailid,dob,gender)
    select g_id,mobno,password,fname,lname,mailid,dob,gender from temp1;
     END //
    DELIMITER ;
```

This code is not working shoiwng error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'selec
t  temp1.fname, 'Person' from temp1;
SET g_id= LAST_INSERT_ID();
insert int' at line 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE cpy()
BEGIN
   DECLARE g_id INT;

   insert into atom /*values*/ (name,type)
   select concat(temp1.fname,temp.lname), 'Person' from temp1;

   SET g_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

   insert into user (id,mobno,password,fname,lname,mailid,dob,gender)
   select g_id,mobno,password,fname,lname,mailid,dob,gender from temp1;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: how to handle duplicate entries

Comment: it is not copying data one by one in both table it is copying all data to atom table