# Cursor to copy distinct record from one table to another

Tags: mysql, cursor

I want to copy all recoreds from temp1 table to anoter two tables I am using cursor for this .

```
 DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE cpyQ()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE g_id INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE v_fn varchar(100);
        DECLARE v_ln varchar(100);
        DECLARE v_email varchar(100);

        declare tcursor for select distinct mailid,fname,lname  from temp1;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET flag = 1;
        OPEN tcursor;
    REPEAT 
          FETCH cursor into v_fn,v_ln, v_email;
            insert into atom(type) values('Person');
            SET g_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
            insert into user(id,fname,lname,mailid) values(g_id,v_fname,v_lname,v_email);
    END REPEAT;
        CLOSE tcursor;
      END//

    DELIMITER
```

this code is showing error

```
 MySQL said: Documentation
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'for select distinct mailid,fname,lname  from temp1;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLE' at line 8
```

How to resolve this

Comment: My aim is to copy distinct data from one table to another table. I think for another 2 table I required cursor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309376/store-procedure-to-copy-a-table-to-two-anoter-table  I tried this code also but this is only copy in to atom table not to user

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple errors in your syntax and don't exit the loop. Try this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cpyQ()
BEGIN
  DECLARE g_id INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE v_fn varchar(100);
  DECLARE v_ln varchar(100);
  DECLARE v_email varchar(100);
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

  declare tcursor cursor for select distinct mailid,fname,lname  from temp1;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
  OPEN tcursor;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH tcursor into v_fn,v_ln, v_email;
    if done then
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    insert into atom(type) values('Person');
    SET g_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    insert into user(id,fname,lname,mailid) values(g_id,v_fn,v_ln,v_email);

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE tcursor;
END
```

Comment: Yes this is working. But I am unable to resolve duplicate entries while copy. Can we specify if duplicate leave it copy new entry??

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking, especially "leave it copy new entry" part. Duplicate entries should be filtered out by `distinct` already. Elaborate please, maybe change your question and append samples of input data with duplicates and the expected results.

Comment: Your answer is near to correct . I dont want duplicat mailids for copy from table but calling above function is showin. `ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'sharma' for key 'mailid'`

Comment: Ah, so only column `mailid` should be unique, not the `mailid,fname,lname` triplet? Ok, then suppose you have two rows with same `mailid` but different `fname` and `lname`. Which row should be left?

Comment: yes only mailid should me unique it is unique key in my table fname and lname can be same

Comment: @xrcwrn you didn't understand my question. The error you get is because there are multiple rows in `temp1` where `mailid = 'sharma'`, but with different `fname` or `lname`. Like `sharma | John | Doe` and `sharma | Jane | Smith`. You have to know which row to copy to your new table. The other cause may be that `user` table is not empty, and there's entry with `mailid = 'sharma'` both in `temp1` and `user` tables.

Comment: Hello I tried above with empty tables but is does not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this query and find this is working

```
insert into atom(id,type) select id,'Person' from user1;
    INSERT INTO user( id, fname, lname, mailid ) SELECT id, fname, lname, mailid FROM user1;
```